# What is this form?

Tags: ancient-greek

Τὴν πεπρωμένην δὲ χρὴ
αἶσαν φέρειν ὡς ῥᾷστα, **γιγνώσκονθ'** ὅτι
τὸ τῆς ἀνάγκης ἔστ' ἀδήριτον σθένος.

What is this declension?

Answer (score 3):

The word is **γιγνώσκοντα**, the acc. m. sg. present participle of γιγνώσκω. The α is elided because of the following vowel, and the τ is aspirated to a θ because of the following rough breathing. It's a masculine accusative singular because it agrees with the implied subject (or just is the subject, if you prefer) of φέρειν in the ACI following χρή.

(If you don't know about [Perseus' morphological analyser](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph), it's an invaluable tool. It also works on elided forms.)

Comment: phero takes the infinitive so the subject of this infinitive is omitted but if it were there it would be masucline accusative singular so the gignosko is modified according to this imaginary declension?

Comment: @user21669 The subject of φέρειν is in the accusative because this is implicitly an *accusativus cum infinitivo* construction after χρή: "It is necessary to bear (= that I bear) τὴν πεπρωμένην αἶσαν ὡς ῥᾷστα, knowing &c."